# Can I have a default value of enum in an AppSheet table?

Tags: google-appsheet

I have a table which I use as a CMS to generate my templated documents. I have a column with ENUM values in it and I'd like to have a default value to be preset in the template. Can I do this in AppSheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value for that column in the table.

similar issue reference [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AppSheet-Q-A/Initial-Value-on-Enum/td-p/357305)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is doable by setting an `INITIAL VALUE` in your [column properties](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106509).

You can check out these documents for more information:

- [Columns: The Essentials](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106674?hl=en&ref_topic=10102630&sjid=5224870128749234443-AP)
- [Define App formulas and Initial values](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10106437#zippy=)

Hope this helps.